# Difference between document.URL and location.href

Tags: javascript, url, dom, location

I know that `document.URL` can not be set, while `location.href` can.

But the Document indicates:

> URL is a replacement for the DOM Level 0 `location.href` property.

So when would we use `document.URL`?

Comment: Whenever you want to read the URL...

Comment: ....in a "modern" manner. `document.location.href` is for ancients.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can **get** the document.URL, but you **can not set** it. 
You can both get and set the `location.href`.

In some webbrowsers, you are able to set the `document.URL` but please don't, as it doesn't work in most browsers.

You gave the answer yourself!

```
var currentURL = document.URL;
alert(currentURL);
```

[Learn more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.URL)

Comment: **The real question**: why does `document.URL` exist when you can do everything with `location.href`?

Answer (score 6):

They're interchangeable as far as getting data is concerned, but as you pointed out document.URL can not be set.  I just always use `location.href` since it's a getter/setter.

Answer (score -10):

Yes and no!

```
alert(document.url);  
document.url="http://www.google.co.uk";  
alert(document.url);
```

Comment: We are talking about `URL` and not `url`. Case matters in Javascript.